# Labeling specific features in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser

In ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop, I work with this point layer and I want to remove all the `Sg` & `Sgs` labels from it:

[image: Example 1]

So I can get this result only:

[image: Example 2]

All the labels are in one field named "field_name" (it is a string type field).
I can seperate the data into two fields or export the features with the numbers only.

I prefer to remove it with SQL Expression. I tried this one:

```py
def FindLabel ([field_name]):
  if "Sg" IN [field_name] :
    pass
  return [field_name]
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error 0 no line 0.
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 2)
```

Comment: This is Python not SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second line includes the word `IN` in uppercase and in python it should be lower case `in`.

Your `return` line should be inside an `else`

Possibly better than an `in` you should just check for the first two characters:

```py
def FindLabel ([field_name]):
    if [field_name][:2] == "Sg" :
        pass
    else:
        return [field_name]
```

Comment: Midavalo, thanks!!. but i don't understand what the use of the  [:2]?

Comment: @newGIS It looks at the string value and takes the characters up to the third (in python counting starts at 0). So `[:2]` leaves "Sg" which are characters 0 and 1, stopping at the third character.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to label the feature with it Object ID (the numbers you posted in the second picture), then you need to open the layer properties, navigate to the display tab and select label all features the same way and use the field Object ID form the drop down. Simple as that.