# Label specific lines in attribute table with syntax- ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, attribute-table, python-parser, syntaxerror

I try to label a point layer for values in lines 1-11 only in this attribute table in field "OBJECTID" with this syntax (i saw this question also [Labeling specific features in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215984/labeling-specific-featurs-in-arcgis-for-desktop)):

```
def FindLabel ( [OBJECTID]):
    for [OBJECTID]:
        return [OBJECTID] [0:10]
```

but i get an error:

```
syntax error: invaild syntax (< string>, line 2)
```

UPDATE:

i get this result when using ahmadhanb SQL query:

[image]

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the Python slice notation used here within the Python parser for labelling in ArcMap, then I would recommend researching at [so] where I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using expression, use the Method "Define classes of features and labels each class differently" -> Use SQL Query and define the range of objectID that you want to label. For example in your case, it will be `"ObjectID" >= 1 AND "ObjectID" <= 10`. Then Choose `field_name` as the desired `Label Field`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what was problem with your approach!

**Rules to be maintained:**

1. Label expression function gets value one by one-So you can not use indexing to get single objectid value from a list of objectid values.
2. If you want to work with the `ObjectID` field then you have to cast
   this field explicitely since it is not python data type as mentioned
   [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).So to use this field in the expression function use
   `int/long` casting/conversion.

see the image-[image: demo]

**Now lets proceed:**
If I maintain the above rules and write a function as below this will work :)

```
def FindLabel ([OBJECTID]):
    if long([OBJECTID])>1 and long([OBJECTID]) <=10:
        label = [OBJECTID]
    elif long([OBJECTID])>10 and long([OBJECTID]) <=20:
        #do something
    elif long([OBJECTID])>20 and long([OBJECTID]) <=30:
        #do something
    #elif...
    #elif...
    #elif...

    else:
        label = None
    return  label
```

**Explanation:**

When I run the above function, It gets one objectid values and checks the condition as stated `if long([OBJECTID])>1 and long([OBJECTID]) <=10` if it passes the `label` variable is populated otherwise set to `None`.

**Other non-programmatic way:**

You can use the [Maplex Labelling Engine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/what-is-maplex-.htm), which is the de-facto standard for all complex and effective labelling.
[image: demo]

**Comparision between two ways:**

If you like programming-

I will say,if you use `expression` you will have a fine grained test and more control.So it can be said that all types of customised labelling can be attained using expression but using SQL you **will not be able** to solve some problem e.g. each lablel should have the common tailing text, like `X district`, `Y district`, `Z district`

If you do not like programming-

In some case, blend of both i.e. `expression` and `SQL` will give you perfect choice e.g. you need to label all `OBJECTID` (2-10) and each lablel should have the common tailing text, like `X district`, `Y district`, `Z district`