# Understanding Label syntax in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser

In the context of this question

[Label specific lines in attribute table with syntax- ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216021/label-specific-lines-in-attribute-table-with-syntax-arcgis)

i build this python phrase in ArcGIS 10.3:

```
def FindLabel ([OBJECTID]):
    if long([OBJECTID])==125 and long([OBJECTID]) ==190:
        label = [SHEM_KID] 
    else:
        label = None
    return  label
```

in order to label only OBJECTID number 125 and 190.
My problem is that nothing happen, and all label disappear from the map. I try also to remove "long" from the code and it also  didn't worked.

Is it possible to do it with python code?

I tried this code also but with no success:

```
def FindLabel ([OBJECTID], [SHEM_KID]):
    if ([OBJECTID])=='125' AND ([OBJECTID]) =='190':
        label = [SHEM_KID] 
    return  label
```

Comment: Checked has to be in list of arguments. Or is correct. See my note to below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @FelixIP's comment, I decided to elaborate more on my answer.

Firstly, you should introduce `[SHEM_KID]` as an argument to your def, i.e., `def FindLabel ([OBJECTID],[SHEM_KID])`, otherwise it cannot know what to print as label.

**Diagnostic of the query**

The first thing you can do is to try running your query on the table, such as `OBJECTID = 125 AND OBJECTID = 190`, to see if it returns any result. If not, you may be trying to use composite condition on a unique id field. If so, you may be required to format your label expression as string.

**Possible workarounds**

As @FelixIP advised the labels are treated as strings (even though the field type is not) and your if statement should be `if ([OBJECTID])== '125' and ([OBJECTID]) =='190':`.

If you are trying to label your features based on a possible unique ID field (OBJECTID) which cannot have two different values therefore does not return anything from a composite conditional (i.e., `AND`). OBJECTID could either be 125 or 190 not both. Try changing `and` to `or` to see if this is what you are looking.

Comment: Apart from this, it is worth to note that all values receded by find label are treated as strings. This ! Objectid! ==125 is going to be false always

Comment: I applied fatih_dur the answer, but I got an error

Comment: I applied fatih_dur the answer, but I get an syntax error

Comment: @newGIS, could you specify a bit more what you receive?

Comment: now it succeed with "or" and not with "OR"

Comment: @newGIS, sorry, I just copied from your second line of code and did not pay attention to python syntax. Now it is fixed.